# Is there any alternative to JTable, that is free and better?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Looking for a free and better alternative to JTable.  Found quite a few good ones, but they aren't free.

To begin with, I want to be able to select cells diagonally (apart from horizontally and vertically).

Answer (score 5):

[JXTable](http://swinglabs.org/docs/components/JXTable/tutorial.jsp) (from [SwingLabs](http://swinglabs.org/index.jsp)) has several nice features ([Column Control](http://swinglabs.org/docs/components/JXTable/tutorial.jsp?step=2#ColumnControl), [Toggle Column Visibility](http://swinglabs.org/docs/components/JXTable/tutorial.jsp?step=2#ColumnSelection), [Highlighting Rows](http://swinglabs.org/docs/components/JXTable/tutorial.jsp?step=3#RowHighlighting), [Sorting Rows](http://swinglabs.org/docs/components/JXTable/tutorial.jsp?step=4#RowSorting), [Filtering Rows](http://swinglabs.org/docs/components/JXTable/tutorial.jsp?step=4#RowSorting), [Horizontal Scroll Control](http://swinglabs.org/docs/components/JXTable/tutorial.jsp?step=2#HorizontalScrolling), and [Resizing Columns](http://swinglabs.org/docs/components/JXTable/tutorial.jsp?step=2#ResizingColumns)), and it is free.

But it's hard to say definitely that you'll like it when you don't say what features you're looking for.

Comment: To begin with, I want to be able to select cells diagonally (apart from horizontally and vertically)

Comment: Please add any relevant requirements to your question. Thanks!

Comment: The links given no longer work.  I also question whether SwingLabs or SwingX are still maintained per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818528/what-is-the-status-of-swinglabs-swingx-post-acquisition with answers that point to releases that are 3-4 years old as of May 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Check out QuickTable:
http://quicktable.org/

Comment: QuickTable is great when using sql db. It's now open source :D http://java.net/projects/quicktable