# What is the status of SwingLabs (SwingX) post acquisition

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I found this older discussion: [Does anyone use the "swingx" extensions to Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452450/does-anyone-use-the-swingx-extensions-to-swing), but I am wondering the current status of SwingLabs, SwingX. A bunch of the download addresses etc are all broken, for example:

https://swingx.dev.java.net the first link on http://swinglabs.org/projects.jsp

https://swingx.dev.java.net/files/documents/2981/153005/swingx-1.6.2-bundle.zip the latest stable download

etc...

Is it simply a matter of substituting a new domain, or has Oracle gutted these activities?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**New Update (Based on Comments)**

As indicated by @kleopatra (core member of the Swing Labs team) the project is dead. Since java.net is no longer available this seems to be dead.

If you still want to use it @emmanuel-bourg referenced this mirror https://github.com/ebourg/swingx and this one https://github.com/RockManJoe64/swingx

**Older Update**

[SwingX 1.6.5-1](https://maven.java.net/#nexus-search;gav~org.swinglabs.swingx~swingx-all~~~~kw,versionexpand) is released (actually, a while back, forgot this thread ;), see [the announcement in the swinglabs forum](https://www.java.net/forum/topic/javadesktop/java-desktop-technologies/swinglabs/swingx-165-1-released). It's a regression release for 1.6.5 which had some painting issues which broke backward compatibility in code build against 1.6.4. The issues were particularly virulent in synth-based LAFs where the synth-installed background painters were ignored, f.i. for JXPanel and JRendererCheckBox. The issues are emergency-fixed, partly by reverting the changes. Future releases are planned to address them more thoroughly.

**Update**

SwingX 1.6.4 is released, see the [announcement in the swinglabs forum](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/javadesktop/java-desktop-technologies/swinglabs/swingx-164-released) at java.net

**Update**

SwingX 1.6.3 is released, artifacts available from [maven rep (at java.net)](https://maven.java.net/index.html#nexus-search;quick~swingx), most probable (we didn't get any alerts :-) from central as well

*Original answer*

unforunately, the project accessibility suffered badly from the migration to kenai infrastructure - and that starting from a low level, as far as working links are involved. In particular, SwingLabs.org rarely ever was up, and everything there is severely outdated.

To get hold of build artefacts, all releases are available from the project's download section

http://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads

(note the description of the file "downloads-broken-due-to-migration-crap ;-)

EDIT:
for your convenience (and since it seems difficult to c&p from the *description* of the file above ;-) the link for a bare-bones view of the download section is, then navigate down to releases

http://java.net/downloads/swingx/

The project itself is alive, a milestone release in the wings - hampered again by infrastructure woes, as described in

http://www.java.net/forum/topic/javadesktop/java-desktop-technologies/swinglabs/latest-swingx-demo-other-stuff

Sorry for the mess, not overly much we can do right now (or in near future) 
Jeanette

Comment: When I when to http://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads there was nothing I could download. Can you not upload the latest stable binaries manually?

Comment: could be ended as another post about Substance

Comment: @kleopatra can we still contribute to it?

Comment: @RomanticElectron yeah, sure - the swinglabs forum isn't very active, but continously monitored, either by me or Karl :-)

Comment: @kleopatra I'm sorry to bother but I can't seem to find any download link in the announcement, nor in the download section, for the 1.6.5-1 version.

Comment: @Djon don't know :-( Didn't visit java.net for a while, forums have moved, can't access maven.java.net (that's where the downloads were kept) ... will try to find out and come back to you

Comment: @Djon the maven rep seems to be slow, but still there - https://maven.java.net/#nexus-search;quick~swingx what you want is swingx-all

Comment: A few years forward and the project seems to progressively fade off of the surface of teh interweb… Only the Nexus repository seem to remain now that java.net is gone, and the [migrated java.net projects list](https://javaee.github.io/other-migrated-projects.html) does not even mention anything about Swing.

Comment: Is SwingX still alive?

Comment: @ceklock unfortunately not - afaik :(

Comment: Can this answer be updated and remove the dead java.net links? I have found it has become very difficult to find anything on swingx and it seems so handy for my application.

Comment: @kleopatra With java.net offline, there appeared to be no remaining location on the internet with the last version of the SwingX development source code. But! A coworker had downloaded the source from SVN and saved it locally before java.net was taken down. And now some shameless self-promotion: I have uploaded this copied source to https://github.com/arotenberg/swingx. It can at least still be viewed now, even if no one is developing it anymore.

Comment: @AaronRotenberg thanks for your effort :) Astonishingly, maven.java.net is still available (the very first reference in all my messy and mostly outdated updates)

Comment: Here is another export with the revision history : https://github.com/ebourg/swingx

Comment: And another export with all the branches and tags (but not the revision numbers) https://github.com/RockManJoe64/swingx

Comment: How can `maven.java.net` still be alive when the rest of `java.net` has been demolished?