# Adding actionListener to jCalendar

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, jcalendar

How would I add an actionListener to the jDayChooser component of an existing jCalendar placed using netbeans?

I would like to only trigger an event only when the day buttons are clicked. as the propertyChange in jCalendar listens to even the jMonthChooser and jYearChooser

P.S. using toedter's jCalendar

Comment: See also [*How to include custom panel with NetBeans GUI Builder?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/816286/230513)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternatively, you can listen for the specific `propertyName`, `"day"`.

```
JDayChooser jdc = new JDayChooser();
jdc.addPropertyChangeListener("day", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getPropertyName()+ ": " + e.getNewValue());
    }
});
```

Addendum: *How do I get it to work on a* `JCalendar`?

Similarly, the `propertyName`, `"calendar"` represents a `Calendar` from which you can `get()` the `DAY_OF_MONTH`.

```
JCalendar jc = new JCalendar();
jc.addPropertyChangeListener("calendar", new PropertyChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        final Calendar c = (Calendar) e.getNewValue();   
        System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));   
    }
});
```

Comment: or Changelistener or ItemListener works for me (could be MXxxListener in some versions)

Comment: it works with a JDayChooser but how do i get it to work on a JCalendar

Comment: Ah, I see; I've updated the answer based on a closer reading of the question.

Comment: @JLawrence isn't there ChangeListener or MChangeListener, if yes then to use that (used old version, little bit modified based on  codesource)

Comment: @mKorbel: I used [v1.4](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/), ~2011, but the [API on the web site](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/api/index.html) is ~2004.

Comment: time to suck newer version, because I used only "modified code" and based code_source

Comment: @mKorbel: I only had two dependent projects: one upgraded cleanly and the other obviated an interim fix [cited here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6824716/230513).

Comment: Sorry this proved unacceptable; naturally, I'd like to learn of a better solution.

Comment: i would like to clarify my question a bit more. My problem is with property change listener. since it triggers even when i change the month or year in a JCalendar. i would only like it to trigger when the day buttons are clicked( 1, 2,3...31). I thought that "day" would work in jc.addPropertyListener("day", new event listener)

Comment: nevermind. found a solution to that by using JDayChooser = jc.getDayChooser(); then using the code before the addendum

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody misses reading the comments. Here's a sample working code.

```
JCalendar jCalendar = new JCalendar();
jCalendar.getDayChooser().addPropertyChangeListener("day", new PropertyChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
      System.out.println(e.getPropertyName()+ ": " + e.getNewValue());
   }
});
```