# JCalendar Build

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, propertychangelistener, jcalendar

Using JCalendar, I have entered the following [code from this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15907328/230513):

```
private void jCalendar2PropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) 
{
    JCalendar jc = new JCalendar();
    jc.addPropertyChangeListener("calendar", new PropertyChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        final Calendar c = (Calendar) evt.getNewValue();   
               System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));     
    }
})
```

but I am not getting a result in the output screen?  Also the build is taking 23 seconds is this normal?
thank you for your help.  Also do I need to create the mouse event?

Comment: read http://www.zfqjava.com/docs/componentpack/calendar.html

Comment: http://flib.sourceforge.net/JCalendar/doc/example/Example1.java

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this; please check your version edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.