# Calendar.getTime returns incorrect date

Tags: java, swing, illegalargumentexception, jcalendar, java.util.calendar

I have a `JCalendar` propertyChangeListener in which I am getting the new selected date using `Calendar newValue = (Calendar) evt.getNewValue()`.
In cases when the old date is 31 and new selected month is one of the 30 days month, when I try to get the value of `newValue.getTime()` it returns incorrect date (1st of the old month in JCalendar 1.2 and 30th of the old month in Jcalendar 1.4). If I do a `setLenient=true`, it throws `Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MONTH`.

Is there any way I can check the old and new date and month and adjust it as per the requirement?

Here's the code:

```
myCalendar.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
   public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
      if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("calendar")) {
        Calendar updatedValue = (Calendar) evt.getNewValue();
        System.out.println(updatedValue); //Prints Month as 10 (Nov) and day as 31
        System.out.println(updatedValue.getTime()); //Prints Month as 11 (Dec) and day as 1
     } 
   } 
}
```

Example:
Current Selected Date -> 31 Dec 2018
calendar returns -> `YEAR=2018,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=48,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=31`

Changing the month to November
calendar returns -> `YEAR=2018,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=1,WEEK_OF_MONTH=6,DAY_OF_MONTH=31`
which is actually incorrect (no 31 day_of_month in month 10 (November))
And 1st Dec gets selected in the JCalendar. I want here 30 Nov to get selected.

The problem is that the propertyChangeListener is called twice. Suppose my date is 31 Dec and I set it to 30 Nov. First time, the date is changed to 30 Dec (to get into the range of Nov I think) and second time it changes the date to 30 Nov. This is visible if I only print the evt.getNewValue() but if I try to set the date by calling some other methods, it gets stuck at 30 Dec only!

Comment: For instance, if my current date selected is 31 Dec 2018 and then I change and select the month of November or September (which doesnt have 31st in it)

Comment: @OleV.V.I have added a snippet.

Comment: Don’t trust the values printed from `System.out.println(updatedValue);`. A `java.util.Calendar` may not have computed its fields after a change. Output from `System.out.println(updatedValue.getTime());` ought to be trustworthy, though. It should print a month abbreviation like `Nov` or `Dec`, though, not a month number.

Comment: @OleV.V. Agreed, but the value printed by `updatedValue.getTime()` is incorrect as I am selecting November month.

Comment: Possibly related: [JCalendar problem (the month February)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818990/jcalendar-problem-the-month-february) (but you probably found that one already).

Comment: Yes it is related and I have already checked it. It says issue fixed in 1.4 for JCalendar but I am still getting the issue with 1.4

Comment: @OleV.V. The problem is that the propertyChangeListener is called twice. Suppose my date is 31 Dec and I set it to 30 Nov. First time, the date is changed to 30 Dec (to get into the range of Nov I think) and second time it changes the date to 30 Nov. This is visible if I only print the `evt.getNewValue()` but if I try to set the date by calling some other methods, it gets stuck at 30 Dec only!

Comment: That sounds like important information, @PratikKumawat. I believe that you should edit it into the question. Sorry, I have no experience with JCalendar, so probably don’t really have suggestions.