# What happened to swing labs or swingx-ws? JXMapKit for Java

Tags: java, swing, gis, swingx

I am new to java and have been looking at few tutorials around GIS or geogrpahical GUI java applications.

Many of them mention and seem to require swingx-ws or swing labs componet and classes.

I have managed to track down some old versions, but they dont seem to have the desired affect in my Jform application.

Basically when I try and drag and drop after adding the .jar to my libraries folder I get the stop smoking sign (joke) or rejected symbol.

I have also added the components to the palette through palette manager and they appear once selected, but when I attempt to add I am shown a javja no class error.

Alot of the links in the tutorials seem to send me to dead sites and are pretty old.

Basically my question is. Is swingx-ws still an active option for adding mapping functionality to java gui apps? And if not, are there any other alternatives?

Thanks in advance

[This is the tutorial I am trying to follow.](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html)

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818528/what-is-the-status-of-swinglabs-swingx-post-acquisition ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what features you are looking for, but take a look at [JMapViewer](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer) and see if it will do the trick.

Comment: Note that JMapViewer by OpenStreetMap is different than JXMapViewer (and JXMapKit) by the SwingX-ws project.

Answer (score 3):

Outdated answer, there are much newer options out there:

I have used [JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/) as a library of map components, but as it is not its intended use, it may not be quite straight forward.

You can also use [gvSIG2](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/software/gvsig-desktop/description) as a library of map components. They rearranged the code on this version(2) to make it simpler to use gvSIG as a library, but this version is still on a beta phase.

Answer (score 2):

A couple years late, but here is the answer you were looking for:

[Internal link to Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314468/slippy-maps-for-java-swing-guis-swingx-ws)